# jQuery reloading incorrectly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a little script to change website language using PHP and Ajax/jQuery. I want page content to refresh without reloading page. Until now i have made this

```
$( "a[data-request]" ).click(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var request = $(this).attr('data-request');
    var what = $(this).attr('data-to');
    xhr.open('GET', '{{ site_url }}' + what + '/' + request);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            $("#body").load(location.href + " #body");
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
});
```

When i click on link

```
<a data-request="english" data-to="home/language" href="#">
```

It succesfuly performs uri request in background and "reloads" #body element, which is whole body

```
<body id="body">
```

However instead of reloading whole page content just disappear and wont reappear again. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `xhr.onload` because it's not implemented in all browsers, use `onreadystatechange` instead

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
  var OK = 200; 
  if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
    if (xhr.status === OK) 
      $("html").html(xhr.response);
  }
};

 xhr.open('GET', '{{ site_url }}' + what + '/' + request); //<-- note must come after above event handler
```

note : this would wipe your button too(one you clicked to  fetch the page).so instead of `body` load that data in some div.

EDIT
I suppose your code is something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(langDropdown).change(function(){
       //get selected language
       //do ajax
    });
});
```

Now suppose you change lang. to Spanish server sends you a Spanish version  so what you get from server is bit like

```
<html>
<head> ....title.....  
<script src=....></script>  //common libs like jquery etc
<script src=my.js></script> //this would be js contaning above code
</head>

<body>
   Esta es una pagina
</body>
</html>
```

Now when you use `document.write` to put the Italian page the `document.ready` won't get called(why? because it gets called only on actual page refresh) so `change` event handlers wont get bound on lang. selection dropdown

Solution:
 code outside `document.ready` will definitely run even when fetched through ajax, but i won't advise that , rather what i would advise is whatever code you want to run on ajax completion (like event binding) write it after `document.write` is success callback/readyState

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
  var OK = 200; 
  if (xhr.readyState === DONE && xhr.status === OK) {
      $("html").html(xhr.response);
      $(langDropdown).change(function(){
          //binding code
        });
   }
};
```

Comment: This works, however my goal is to reload whole page as it changes language. so if i only reload one certain element - other elements will show old language, while specific element will display in new language.

Comment: this still messes up a bit my html. i probably will stivk with page simple refreshing. but thank you.

Comment: Tell me the issue , try `document.write()` instead of `$('html').html()`

Comment: document.write() works on first change - new language shows. but then if i try to switch language again - page does not refresh, language does not update. only on manual refresh new language is displayed

Comment: In ajax respose what portion of the new page are you sending? I mean just body or everything including `<html>` and `<head>`?

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var request = $(this).attr('data-request');
    var what = $(this).attr('data-to');
    xhr.open('GET', '{{ site_url }}' + what + '/' + request);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //$("html").html(xhr.response);
            document.write(xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();

Comment: No don't want js show me php.Anyway i will try to explain in edit